# ADB does not work in boot loader mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, adb, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have a Galaxy Nexus 'maguro' and a laptop with Ubuntu 12.10. I'm trying to install Ubuntu Touch preview. I installed the adb and fastboot packages, and adb detects the device when it is booted in to Android. But when I do a reboot-bootloader, it no longer turns up in the devices list.

Comment: Are you checking `adb devices`? 'Cause that's not where it will be when it's at the bootloader - you should see it under `fastboot devices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Boot** loader mode" is also known as "fast **boot** mode" hence you need to use **[fastboot](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Android_SDK#Fastboot)** utility to access the device.  This utility is part of Android SDK, and can be found in the same location as adb - `<SDK install location>\platform-tools\`